# No member named 'sum' in 'std::slice_array<int>'

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's a code that can't be compiled with any at least c+++11-conform compiler (tried at godbolt):

```
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Whatever {
public:
    int sliceSum(const std::vector<int>& nums, int k) const {
        std::valarray<int> data(nums.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            data[i] = nums[i];
        }
        // Here we have St11slice_arrayIiE
        std::cout << typeid(decltype(data[std::slice(0, k, 1)])).name() << std::endl;
        return data[std::slice(0, k, 1)].sum();
    }
};

class Matrix {
    std::valarray<int> data;
    int dim;
 public:
    Matrix(int r, int c) : data(r*c), dim(c) {}
    int& operator()(int r, int c) {return data[r*dim + c];}
    int trace() const {
        // Here we have St5_ExprISt6_SClosISt9_ValArrayiEiE
        std::cout << typeid(decltype(data[std::slice(0, dim, 1)])).name() << std::endl;
        return data[std::slice(0, dim, 1)].sum();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Matrix m(3,3);
    int n = 0;
    for(int r=0; r<3; ++r)
       for(int c=0; c<3; ++c)
           m(r, c) = ++n;
    Whatever s;
    s.sliceSum({1,2,3}, 3);
    m.trace();
}
```

Class `Matrix` is taken from `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice` and class `Whatever` is mine.

So I don't understand what the problem is and why types are different in two identic (?) cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in the `Matrix` case `data` is `const` (since the method is `const` and `data` is a member), whereas in the `Whatever` case `data` is not `const` (since it's declared non-const in the method itself).

If you look at the [`operator[]` declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_at) for `std::valarray`, you see that it has two `operator[]` that accept a slice parameter, one `const` and one not `const`.

The `const` version returns `std::valarray`, which has a `sum` method, the `non-const` returns `std::slice_array`, which does not.

To fix this, wrap the result in a `std::valarray`:

```
return std::valarray(data[std::slice(0, k, 1)]).sum();
```